# My PWA application needs to load (embed) another application, when the PWA gets started

Tags: cors, cross-domain, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, custom-error-pages

I have a PWA application running at localhost:{port1} and when this PWA is up and running it needs to load the contents from another application(app1) that is up and running at localhost:{port2}, i.e; the landing page of PWA should actually be my app1, more like PWA is embeding app1.

I have registered the ServiceWorker.js at the root of my PWA application. Now when the request is being made to localhost:{port2}, the service worker intercepts the network requests for the assets in app1 and thus it fails. I can see in the network tab http://localhost:{port1}/{my app1 path}/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.2b13baa7.eot and it returns with 404.

Any help on this is appreciated.

I tried to ignore the calls going to my .eot in fetch request of PWA service worker file, but that did not work.
Tried to again call http://localhost:{port2}/{my app1 path}/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.2b13baa7.eot on encountering requests with .eot , but did not work.

I do not have experience working with service workers and PWA. This is the first time I am trying.